# Fraction field of $F[x,y,z]/(x^4+y^4+zy)$ equal to $F(y,z)[x]/(x^4+y^4+zy)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Why is the fraction field of $F[x,y,z]/(x^4+y^4+zy)$ equal to $F(y,z)[x]/(x^4+y^4+zy)$? Is there a general formula to compute the fraction field of $F[x_1,...,x_n]/(f)$ or $F[x_1,...,x_n]/(f_1,...,f_m)$

Comment: $F[x_1,...,x_n]/(x^2+y^4+zy)$ makes no sense. The variables in the polynomial ring are $x_i$, but the polynomial you divide out by is generated by a polynomial in $x, y, z$.

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo, I edited.

Comment: Did you really mean to change from “$/(x^2+y^4+zy)$” to “$/(x^4+y^4+zy)$” ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

This is because $\;F(y,z)\longrightarrow F(y,z)[x]/(x^4+y^4+zy)$ is an integral morphism and we have the following well-known result:

> Let $B$ be an integral domain, $A$ a subring of $B$ such that $B$ is integral over $A$.  Then $B$ is a field if and only if  $A$ is a field.

Comment: Thank you, but what is $A$ and $B$? is $A=F(y,z)$ and $B=F[x,y,z]/(x^4+y^4+zy)$? When you say the morphism is integral, does it mean that $F[x,y,z]/(x^4+y^4+zy)$ is integral over $F(y,z)[x]/(x^4+y^4+zy)$?

Comment: No, I mean $B=F(y,z)[x]/(x^4+y^4+zy)$ is integral over $A=F(y,z)$.